# Can we apply styles to the in-context window?

Tags: paypal

Are we able to provide custom styling to the `paypal` in-context window? There is a bit of x overflow on the horizontal of the `paypal` in-context window on large screens that isn't needed and I would like to know if I can hide it with some css.

Example of the paypal in-context window:

[image: BQD8y]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With incontext checkout you cannot customize the window with CSS. You can customize the button images on your page, but you cannot change the PayPal hosted page. 
[In Context Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/)
Within the in Context Integration is the demo and some sample code.

[In Context Advanced Settings and Custom Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/#advanced-settings)